# Garageband Save & Save As & Export Buttons Do Not Function

Tags: audio, midi

I recently started making music using GarageBand's MIDI software. I've made it up to a certain point, where losing all my progress would be disastrous.

Here's the issue I have:
When I go to File > Save/Save As or just cmd+S or cmd+shift+S, or Share > Export Song to Disk, instead of functioning and saving the file (I checked in Finder; last time I exited the app without saving due to this issue, the untitled garageband file disappeared) properly onto the app, it would either do nothing or give me the rainbow wheel of death for 10-20 seconds and then proceed to not function.

[image: Finder directory of Garageband file]

I've searched online for answers to this, and there were several (2) users I found that had the same problem. Their post either had no answer or the answer was unintuitive (such as always using a different, more complicated method to save, like messing around with the garageband files themselves *everytime* to save).

I'm looking for an answer to this issue that would result in slightly more convenient, one-time edits to the app / any software beneath that would fix this issue, if there are any. However, if the community has any alternate way to ***save*** the file right now, I would greatly appreciate it.

======

Also:
Since I'd assume most of the solutions would involve closing the app and then making edits, then reinstalling it, please tell me if I could just copy the notes (not the tracks) onto a text document and paste it into the new file after. I would prefer to save my music.

Comment: Sorry if I'm repeating this, but the main thing I want to know for now is if I can copy and paste all the notes and save it into a text doc, and then open a new garageband file and it would still paste correctly into that file.

Answer (score -1):

Try this . . .
First QUIT Garageband  (yes you will lose unsaved work).
Find the Garageband folder where all the .BAND files are saved.  Usually it is in Users -> Username -> Music -> Garageband.
Move older .band files into another folder  (EG: "Garageband OLD")
Then start a new project (or open a project still in the Garageband folder).
Save and Save-As should now work.
It seems there is some sort of file limit for the Garageband folder.  In my case the file limit is either 170 .band files or about 125GB.
I am currently using Garageband 10.3.5 on High Sierra.